# Erdös's sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've read that the sequence $\left(e_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
$$
e_0=1\text{ and } \ e_n=e_{\left\lfloor \,n/2 \right\rfloor}+e_{\left\lfloor \,n/3 \right\rfloor}+e_{\left\lfloor \,n/6 \right\rfloor}
$$
satisfies the beautiful equality
$$
\frac{e_n}{n} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}\frac{12}{\ln\left(432\right)}
$$
I read the proof of Erdös himself but he proves the general case. Is there an easier way to prove this equality ? I would be curious to see it !